# Strange markers showing up on pandas boxplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a boxplot with the code below that looks like the image below and I can't figure out why there are some strange plus sign markers appearing above the Atlantic Coast and Pacific coast boxes. Why are these '+' markers showing up?

```
boxplot_2015 = data_2015.boxplot(column = 'LCOE', by = 'Coastal Region', return_type = 'axes')
plt.title('LCOE by Region')
plt.suptitle('')
plt.xlabel('Region')
plt.ylabel('LCOE ($/MWh)')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Those plus signs are observations that outside of some range. You'll have to read the docs to see what range what the box plot is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are `fliers`.  If you don't like them use `showfliers=False`

[docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

> fliers: points representing data that extend beyond the whiskers (fliers).

***adjust your code***

```
boxplot_2015 = data_2015.boxplot(
    column = 'LCOE', by = 'Coastal Region',
    return_type = 'axes', showfliers=False)
plt.title('LCOE by Region')
plt.suptitle('')
plt.xlabel('Region')
plt.ylabel('LCOE ($/MWh)')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

---

***demonstration***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
df.boxplot(ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('With Fliers')
df.boxplot(ax=axes[1], showfliers=False)
axes[1].set_title('Without Fliers')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks piRSquared for the in depth explaination! I am still quite new to pandas and matplotlib so this helps a lot.